# QML reference errors

Tags: qt, reference, qml, qt-creator

I have a small QML-project and I'm facing a problem with qml component references. So I'm trying to start the NumComponent.qml's numberTimer from startButton in the main.qml.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    NumComponent{} //my component written in NumComponent.qml

    Rectangle{
        id: startButton
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: parent.height * 0.2
        width: height
        color: "lightblue"

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                numberTimer.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NumComponent.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: numberRect
    color: "red"
    height: parent.height * 0.4
    width: height

    Text{
        id: numberText
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: ""
    }
    Timer{
        id: numberTimer
        interval: 100
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            numberText.text = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error: "qrc:/main.qml:22: ReferenceError: numberRect is not defined"

Comment: That is because NumComponent is an enclosed object. You can either use [Connections](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#using-the-connections-type) or expose numberRect (or your numberTimer) as a [custom property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-attributes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give your NumComponent in main.qml an id:

   ```
   NumComponent{
     id: numComponent
   } //my component written in NumComponent.qml
   ```
2. change your onClicked handler to:

   numComponent.startTimer();

Another variant:

2. Add to your numberRect a property alias:

   ```
   property alias timed: numberTimer.running
   ```
3. Change you onClicked handler in main to:

   numComponent.timed = !numComponent.timed;
4. Add to your NumComponent.qml in your root item:

   function startTimer() {
      numberTimer.start();
   }

Now you can start and stop your timer.